# jquery if condition for css display

Tags: jquery, css

I have a menu with some links which hides/shows div pages.

On the first page I have youtube video playing, but if I click another link, the video dissapears as another div will be showing, but the video keeps playing..

I found the way of how to stop the video etc, but while debugging, I can not seem to make my alert to go off while I write this:

```
if ( $("#main").css('display') == 'none')
{
    alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
}
```

If I were to change **none** to **block** the alert box will appear once the page loads up. So how come it does not show up once the id for **main** changes to none (when I click another menu link)?

**EDITED:**

Thats how I set the attributes to **none** with the menu links:

```
$('.tabs a').on( "click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr('data-related'); 
    $(".frame div").each(function(){
        $(this).hide();
        if($(this).attr('id') == id) {
            $(this).show();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Do you explicitly set the display attribute to none?

Comment: If I set my div id to **none** it will display the alert on page load, but if I click other menu links which will make #main div change from none to block, then it will not show up again. It shows alert if the if condition matches on page load only, but once is changed withing the page, it will not show up

Comment: How do you set attribute to none?

Comment: @L.Kolar see my edit to the original question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you calling a function with that if statement anywhere in your js or do you just have the if statement in your js not inside a function?  If you just have the if statement in there it will only evaluate it on page load, it won't keep running the if statement every time the css changes. you need to put the if statement into a function and call that function every time you change the css

Comment: No, its not in the funcion. Well atleast now I know what's the problem. Thanks for that

Comment: No problem, can you please upvote and accept my answer?